# Radio button with title and subtitle label

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons that look like buttons.

[**Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/sNJCB6yKt31Et7bQrKKO?p=preview) the code:

```
<div id='vaccine-selector-container' class="switch-field">
        <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
            <input type='radio' id='rb-dtp' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='DTP' autocomplete='off' checked>
            <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-dtp'>DTP</label>
            <label class='custom-control-label-help' for='rb-dtp'>Vaccine against diphtheria, tetanus, pertussis</label>
        </span>
        <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
            <input type='radio' id='rb-mmr' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='MMR' autocomplete='off'>
            <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-mmr'>MMR</label>
            <label class='custom-control-label-help' for='rb-mmr'>Vaccine against measles, mumps and rubella</label>
        </span>     
        <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
            <input type='radio' id='rb-pol' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='POL' autocomplete='off'>
            <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-pol'>POL</label>
            <label class='custom-control-labelHelp' for='rb-pol'>Vaccine against poliomyelitis</label>
        </span>
    </div>
```

But what I want is this: a "title" label and a "subtitle" label.

[image]

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap both the labels under one label and give 'for' attribute for this parent label and may change those separate inner labels into any other tag (for eg: p tag).

```
<div id='vaccine-selector-container' class="switch-field">
        <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
            <input type='radio' id='rb-dtp' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='DTP' autocomplete='off' checked>
            <label for='rb-dtp'>
                <p class='custom-control-label'>DTP</p>
                <p class='custom-control-label-help'>Vaccine against diphtheria, tetanus, pertussis</p>
            </label>

        </span>
        <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
            <input type='radio' id='rb-mmr' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='MMR' autocomplete='off'>
            <label for='rb-mmr'>
                <p class='custom-control-label'>MMR</p>
                <p class='custom-control-label-help'>Vaccine against measles, mumps and rubella</p>
            </label>

        </span>     
        <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
            <input type='radio' id='rb-pol' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='POL' autocomplete='off'>
            <label for='rb-pol'>
                <p class='custom-control-label'>POL</p>
                <p class='custom-control-labelHelp' for='rb-pol'>Vaccine against poliomyelitis</p>
            </label>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is what you are trying to achieve, I hope this could be helpful

```
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Sub Title</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I would not recommend using a <h2> as it isn't a headline at that point. Else it's a solid anwer in my opinion :)

Comment: I have changed it to <h3>, however I guess it could be even a span with a dedicated class in order to customise it.

Answer (score 0):

Children is one way ([demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/D4npmxGHtzNw8lCLT4j8?p=info)):

```
    <div id='vaccine-selector-container' class="switch-field">
        <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
            <input type='radio' id='rb-dtp' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='DTP' autocomplete='off' checked>
            <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-dtp'>
              <div>DTP</div>
              <label class='custom-control-label-help' for='rb-dtp'>Vaccine against diphtheria, tetanus, pertussis</label>
            </label>

        </span>
        <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
            <input type='radio' id='rb-mmr' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='MMR' autocomplete='off'>
            <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-mmr'>
              <div>MMR</div>
              <label class='custom-control-label-help' for='rb-mmr'>Vaccine against measles, mumps and rubella</label>
            </label>

        </span>     
        <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
            <input type='radio' id='rb-pol' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='POL' autocomplete='off'>
            <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-pol'>
              <div>POL</div>
                <label class='custom-control-labelHelp' for='rb-pol'>Vaccine against poliomyelitis</label>
            </label>

        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the radio buttons inside labels

```
   <span class='custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline'>
                    <label class='custom-control-label' for='rb-dtp'><input type='radio' id='rb-dtp' name='vaccine-selector' class='custom-control-input' value='DTP' autocomplete='off' checked>   DTP                 <label class='custom-control-label-help' for='rb-dtp'>              Vaccine against diphtheria, tetanus, pertussis</label>
</label>


            </span>
```

and

```
.switch-field label {
width:40%;
}
```